# handling media files in the URL

Tags: c#, url, umbraco

Based on a certain condition I m redirecting user to login page and specifying the return url as below

```
   context.Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?retUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Url.ToString()));
```

A setting in webconfig
`<add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls"  value="false"/>` adds ".aspx" extension to the url but when I m requesting any media files like a pdf document the return url becomes                        `retUrl=http%3a%2f%2flocal.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk%2fcalderdale%2f1.pdf.aspx`

how can we possibly exclude media files in the above setting? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its the umbracoUseDirectoryUrls that's causing the problem - I think your problem is because Umbraco doesn't know how to handle your pdfs properly.  It looks like Umbraco is simply seeing your pdf as content rather than media, which is why its appending the .aspx.  I think if you get your site handling pdfs as media it will solve your issue.

There is some guidance here on adding a pdf media type (http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/13593-Pdf-Document-Media-Type)